# NodeJS: How to do a many to many relation using Loopback4

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

I'm building a blog API using the Loopback 4 framework and I didn't find in documentation or any article on the internet for how to do many to many relationships (Posts and Categories)

So my question is: How to do such a relation in LoopBack 4? and If not supported is there a workaround!

Also, another question, how to do a cascade ( update, insert ) and update on duplication using LoopBack 4?

Comment: I found your missing docs: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasMany-relation.html :)

Comment: This is a `one to many` relations!!!! many to many is not on the loopback documentations

Comment: please recheck the link and read what inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoopBack 4 doesn't currently support hasAndBelongsToMany relation. You'll need to create your own junction table/Model using a [hasManyThrough relation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasManyThrough-relation.html).

See the relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2308